# Unable to start kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I've installed latest  binaries of both elasticsearch/kibana from AUR.
I am unable to start the kibana service. It keeps failing with the following error.

```
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]: Unhandled Promise rejection detected:
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]: TypeError: Cannot set property 'writecb' of undefined
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]:     at LogInterceptor.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:185:14)
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]:     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:352:12)
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]:     at LogInterceptor.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:303:10)
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]:     at Monitor.push (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@elastic/good/lib/monitor.js:207:30)
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]:     at Monitor._logHandler (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/@elastic/good/lib/monitor.js:40:18)
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]:     at module.exports.internals.Podium.internals.Podium.emit (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/podium/lib/index.js:220:49)
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]:     at module.exports.internals.Core._log (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/hapi/lib/core.js:584:21)
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]:     at module.exports.internals.Core.log (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/hapi/lib/core.js:562:21)
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]:     at internals.Server.log (/usr/share/kibana/node_modules/hapi/lib/server.js:312:27)
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]:     at KbnServer._default (/usr/share/kibana/src/optimize/index.js:68:12)
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]:     at async KbnServer.mixin (/usr/share/kibana/src/legacy/server/kbn_server.js:150:7)
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]:     at async KbnServer.listen (/usr/share/kibana/src/legacy/server/kbn_server.js:162:5)
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]:     at async LegacyService.createKbnServer (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/legacy/legacy_service.js:285:9)
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]:     at async LegacyService.start (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/legacy/legacy_service.js:159:24)
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]:     at async Server.start (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/server.js:193:5)
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]:     at async Root.start (/usr/share/kibana/src/core/server/root/index.js:55:14)
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle node[1771]: Terminating process...
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle systemd[1]: kibana.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 05 15:51:16 castle systemd[1]: kibana.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
```

All configurations in elasticsearch/kibana are default. I can curl elasticsearch from console.
Any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that even the latest kibana 7 does not support nodejs 14, and requires nodejs 10.

```sh
pacman -S nodejs-lts-dubnium
```

This will, however, not be enough. See [#84266](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/84266), kibana make an hard error if the nodejs version deosn't match exactly. So you will need to edit `/usr/share/kibana/package.json` and make change to the node version to match your currently installed nodejs dubnium... use `node -v` this should be something like `10.x.x`

Running that should get you going.

Also, I wouldn't recommend running stuff from the AUR unless you have a good use case, especially when both kibana and elasticsearch are in the main repositories. Though the problem was not AUR specific this time.

Comment: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/67415?project=5&string=kibana

Comment: Thanks, installing an older version of nodejs worked for me. However, `nodejs-lts-dubnium`  wasn't available in the official pacman repo (I guess it has been removed since you wrote your reply). I installed `nodejs-lts-fermium` instead (this is nodejs version 14), and it worked.